# Find duplicates in a pandas dataframe column that have any different value in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, filter

I have a dataframe that has a unique ID per person, their name, street, email and date. The dataframe may contain blanks and different characters like in this example:

```
ID  Name    Street        Email       Date
1   Paulo   street #1   p@aa.com    2001-01-20
1   Paulo   street #1   p@aa.com    20-Jan
1   Paulo   street #1   p@aa.com    2001-01-20
2   Maria   street #2   m@aa.com    2020-01-01
2   Mari    street #2   m@aa.com    2020-01-01
3   Peter                  xx
4   Josh    street #4   j@aa.com    
4   Josh    street #4   j@aa.com
```

I need a way to filter this dataframe by finding the IDs that repeats in column "ID" and return all rows that have any different value in any other of the columns. If this case happens, return all rows with the same ID, resulting in this dataframe:

```
ID  Name    Street        Email       Date
1   Paulo   street #1   p@aa.com    2001-01-20
1   Paulo   street #1   p@aa.com    20-Jan
1   Paulo   street #1   p@aa.com    2001-01-20
2   Maria   street #2   m@aa.com    2020-01-01
2   Mari    street #2   m@aa.com    2020-01-01
```

What would be the best solution for it?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for all columns and filter if greater like `1` for any column, last remove duplciates by all columns by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df[df.groupby('ID').transform('nunique').gt(1).any(axis=1)].drop_duplicates()
print (df)
   ID   Name     Street     Email        Date
0   1  Paulo  street #1  p@aa.com  2001-01-20
1   1  Paulo  street #1  p@aa.com      20-Jan
3   2  Maria  street #2  m@aa.com  2020-01-01
4   2   Mari  street #2  m@aa.com  2020-01-01
```

Comment: Hello, thank you! Is there a way that I could return all 3 rows for the ID 1? We have 2 rows being the same value and 1 different, in this case I would like to return all rows with that ID. Thanks!

Comment: @PauloCortez - only remove `.drop_duplicates()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nunique` to count distinct elements so that id 4 will not be returned:

```py
df = df.groupby('ID').filter(
    lambda x: x['ID'].count() > 1 and (
                  x['Name'].nunique() > 1 
               or x['Street'].nunique() > 1 
               or x['Email'].nunique() > 1 
               or x['Date'].nunique() > 1
    ))
```